# Woocommerce replace add to cart url to link to product page

Tags: woocommerce

I am using this shortcode to display products [product_category category="extras" orderby="date"].

Variable products show "select options" and single products show "add to cart". I was able to change text of both to say "View Product".

The problem now is that I need to change the url of those that used to say "add to cart", because they don't link to the product page but to "Add to the cart".

I know I can edit the woocommerce template, but I would need this as a function to be added to function.php

I don't need any button involved, just replacing the url.

So again purpose:
Replace/redirect "Add to Cart" url to link to product page (only in loop, obviously not in product page).

Can someone help?

Comment: Something like this would do, but it doesn't work, it wasn't updated to last version I guess.

[link](http://www.fix-css.com/2013/10/replace-add-to-cart-button-in-products-category-list-with-a-link-to-single-product-page-in-woocommerce/)

Then in the end they mention functions to also include buttons, I don't need that, I just need a function to replace the url.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If someone does elect to change the woocommerce file (in child theme of course!).

In file: /loop/add-to-cart.php

Change:

```php
global $product;

echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
    sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="button %s product_type_%s">%s</a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( $product->id ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
        $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
        esc_attr( $product->product_type ),
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    ),
$product );
```

To:

```php
global $product;

if ( $product->product_type == "simple" ) {
    $simpleURL = get_permalink();
    $simpleLabel =  "View Product";  // BUTTON LABEL HERE
} else {
    $simpleURL =  $product->add_to_cart_url();  
    $simpleLabel = $product->add_to_cart_text();
};

echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
    sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="button %s product_type_%s">%s</a>',
        esc_url( $simpleURL ),
        esc_attr( $product->id ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
        $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
        esc_attr( $product->product_type ),
        esc_html( $simpleLabel )
    ),
$product );
```

Comment: This works great. But it seems my add to cart button loses "AJAX functionality". Not sure if your codes affect it.

Comment: With WC 5.7.1: I added `ajax_add_to_cart` class to the button and AJAX was back again.
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

In the funtions.php of you theme add this code:

```
/*STEP 1 - REMOVE ADD TO CART BUTTON ON PRODUCT ARCHIVE (SHOP) */

 function remove_loop_button(){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
    }
    add_action('init','remove_loop_button');

    /*STEP 2 -ADD NEW BUTTON THAT LINKS TO PRODUCT PAGE FOR EACH PRODUCT */

        add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','replace_add_to_cart');
        function replace_add_to_cart() {
            global $product;
            $link = $product->get_permalink();

            echo '<p style="text-align:center;margin-top:10px;">';
            $currentlang = get_bloginfo('language');
            //for multilanguage
            if($currentlang=="en-GB"){
                echo do_shortcode('<a  href="'.$link.'" class="button addtocartbutton">View Product</a>');
            } elseif($currentlang=="fr-FR"){
                echo do_shortcode('<a  href="'.$link.'" class="button addtocartbutton">Voir le produit</a>');
            }else {
               echo do_shortcode('<a  href="'.$link.'" class="button addtocartbutton">Ver Producto</a>');   
            }
            echo '</p>';
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can disable AJAX add-to-cart functionality in the WooCommerce settings.

If that isn't satisfactory for some reason you can take a look at the `loop/add-to-cart.php` template. The add to cart link is filterable. If you look at `add-to-cart.js` you can see that the AJAX add to cart function is triggered for any link with the `add_to_cart button` class, and *only* works for buttons with the `product_type_simple` class.... ie: only for simple products. Depending on your styles, you could either remove the product type class or the `add_to_cart_button` class from the link. In the example below, I have removed the `add_to_cart_button` class.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'so_26247988_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );
function so_26247988_add_to_cart_link( $link, $product ){
    $link = sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="button product_type_%s">%s</a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( $product->id ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
        esc_attr( $product->product_type ),
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    )
    return $link;
}
```